# how to create a model without tabel

Tags: php, yii

I want to send mails to users for which Iam creating a model with name 'Common'. Common model has the function 'test' to send mails. But the model is giving error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Common::model()
```

here is my model code:

```
<?php
class Common extends CFormModel
{
   public $from;
   public $to;

  public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('from, to', 'required'),
        );
    }

  public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
        'from' => 'From',
        'to' => 'To',
        );
    }
 public function test($id)
    {
      print_r($id); die("sfbvjzsb");
  ------------------------------------------
              sending mail code
--------------------------------------------
    }

}

?>
```

Iam calling the model in controller as below:

```
Common::model()->test($group_id);
```

Where Iam doing wrong?

Comment: make sure that the model's class name is same as the file name. So, if you have created a model with class name `Common` name that php file `Common.php`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't have a static method named model().

You can do this:

```
$c = new Common();
$c->test($group_id);
```

Or , if you change the declaration of the test function to:

```
public static function test($id)
```

then you will be able to call it statically like this:

```
Common::test($group_id);
```